# Grouping and queuing transactions

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I am totally new to Ethereum and I'm more familiar to the Bitcoin blockchain.

Is there a way to group transactions?

Suppose I want transactions of multiple users to get grouped together and validated in one time; the transactions being triggered when I have enough transactions in the queue.

Is there a way to do that through some smart contract ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. It depends on what you mean.

In Bitcoin you can have multiple inputs and multiple inputs so you can combine tx fees. In Ethereum, a transaction is from one address to another address. If the "to" is a smart contract, then it could potentially do something with the transaction and send call functions/send ETH to multiple addresses (a "transaction" from inside a contract is called an "internal transaction", but that's a misnomer because it's not a real transaction).

Since smart contracts on Ethereum on turing complete, you can group contracts together if you want, you just can't full group tx fees. However, if smart contract A had a requirement like a 20 ETH minimum deposit, you could write another smart contract B that took multiple transactions and as soon as the total hit 20 ETH, it would send it to contract A. This allows people to "group" transactions in a way.